# Cross compiling druid for ARM on MacOS

Tags: linux, rust, raspberry-pi, linker-errors, gtk3

I'm trying to cross compile a [linebender/druid](https://github.com/linebender/druid) hello-world for a raspberry pi model 3B using a MacBook Pro. I'm using [rustembedded-cross](https://github.com/rust-embedded/cross) project and its **armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf** toochain to do this. I then realised that this wasn't working, probably because the toolchain that is used didn't have **gtk-3** (a pre-requisite of Druid). No problem, you can extend the [image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/rustembedded/cross/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/images/sha256-81fbdc69d8678d85bb526605f583be3156876ab247fc91139ff308481ff2e53c?context=explore) and supply config to cross to tell it to use this instead. From there I installed `gtk3.0` & `libgtk-3-dev`.

This failed because the version of `gtk` was slightly below the requirement so I rebuilt the toolchain [image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/rustembedded/cross/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/images/sha256-81fbdc69d8678d85bb526605f583be3156876ab247fc91139ff308481ff2e53c?context=explore) and bumped it's base image of ubuntu to 18.

It compiled! However it doesn't link. The linker fails with the error below.

If I run
`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
I receive

```
-lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

My question is: why is this happening, how do I fix?

```
error: linking with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-L" "/rust/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib" "/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/rust_druid-74b3b342d33bbf8f.13znndaj71lv0t24.rcgu.o" "/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/deps/rust_druid-74b3b342d33bbf8f.13zvkdulzx8wlkqq.rcgu.o"

....<ELIDED>....
"/rust/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libcore-76f623378444b03d.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/rust/lib/rustlib/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libcompiler_builtins-cc04ad48cc548447.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgtk-3" "-lgdk-3" "-lpangocairo-1.0" "-lpango-1.0" "-latk-1.0" "-lcairo-gobject" "-lcairo" "-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0" "-lgio-2.0" "-lgobject-2.0" "-lglib-2.0" "-latk-1.0" "-lgobject-2.0" "-lglib-2.0" "-lgdk-3" "-lpangocairo-1.0" "-lpango-1.0" "-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0" "-lcairo-gobject" "-lcairo" "-lgobject-2.0" "-lglib-2.0" "-lpango-1.0" "-lgobject-2.0" "-lglib-2.0" "-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0" "-lgobject-2.0" "-lglib-2.0" "-lgio-2.0" "-lgobject-2.0" "-lglib-2.0" "-lgobject-2.0" "-lglib-2.0" "-lcairo-gobject" "-lcairo" "-lgobject-2.0" "-lglib-2.0" "-lglib-2.0" "-lutil" "-ldl" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lgcc_s" "-lc" "-lm" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lutil" "-ldl" "-lutil"

          = note: /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-3
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The linker command-line includes the path for the target's `/lib`, but the missing libs are probably in `/usr/lib`